# RMI multiple clients

Tags: java, rmi

Does RMI handles multiple clients by itself? i.e.

1. is it possible to use a server function by multiple clients at the same time?
2. if no, how can I do such a thing?
3. if yes, how it works? does it make a new thread for each *call*? if one clients blocks the function what would happen with the next client? etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes

> how it works? does it make a new thread for each call? if one clients blocks the function what would happen with the next client? etc.

It creates a thread for each client connection.

If one client calls a synchronized method or one which blocks other calls, calls made by other threads will block until that call releases the resource.

It sounds like you already worked out the answers, do you have a more specific doubt?

Comment: @MBZ 'Unicast' means point-to-point, as opposed to multicast. This piece of RMI terminology is most unfortunate, as it implies that there could be such as thing as a `MulticastRemoteObject`. If you think about the nature of RMI that is obviously false.

Answer (score 2):

Yes  RMI does handles multiple clients, but you must make your server **threadsafe** , RMI will  dispatch multiple threads into a single server object if multiple clients simultanuosly
make methods call on it so if your server isn't threadsafe your application will fail.